# How to use corrupted spells?

Tags: path-of-exile

Every corrupted area yields a corrupted spell. But I can't use them. Why? Should I de-corrupted them? How so?

It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what he is asking is how to cleanse the glyph so it isn't corrupted anymore, the difference between a normal and corrupted is that the later one need charging normally 30 monsters killed before using it once each time, the normal (not corrupted) doesn't need the kills, as long as you have enough mana you can cast it as many times as you want.. if someone know what to do to clean them of corruption please post the answer "I WHANT TO KNOW TOO!" XD

Comment: @Anonimo The "corrupted" effect prevents use of any currency items on said item, so no, there's no way to get rid of a "corrupted" effect.

Answer (score 11):

[Vaal Skill Gem](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Vaal_Skill_Gem)

> Vaal Skills may be used only when enough **souls have been collected
>   from slain enemies**. Collected souls are **saved to the zone instance
>   they were gathered in**. **Changing zones** or resetting the instance will
>   **start a new soul counter**, but returning to **a prior instance will
>   "remember" the souls you left with**. Collected souls are lost if the
>   Vaal Skill Gem is removed from its socket.

I tested it all, everything is accurate. I never saw anything about putting the vaal gem in main weapon or something. You can put it anywhere you want.

*(in your gear I mean, you pervert)*

Answer (score 2):

Corrupted gems have to be "charged", to charge a gem, keep killing monsters with it equipped (not in your secondary weapon slot though).

They work like potions, in that you can use them after killing enough monsters to recharge them.

Comment: Changing maps clears the charges.  The wiki says the charges are stored per map. I have not tested going back to a map and seeing if I still have charges.

Comment: @mmatthews I have, and that's how it works. It remembers how many you killed in a certain map. This also applies to switching instances, as it will remember amount of kills in the one you got them in.

Answer (score 0):

Lemme tell you about Corrupted gems:

A corrupted gem is a much more powerful version of a regular gem, but can only be activated once it is filled up with "souls" (i.e. you must kill enough mobs to be able to use it once, after which you have to refill it again. Consider it a "pacing mechanic" to balance the fact of how awesome it is).

The effect that says "Corrupted" can be found on weapons and gems alike, or added through the use of a Corrupted Orb. As a general rule, **an item that is "corrupted" can NOT be crafted on**. Hence, it is the final stage of crafting. Corrupting an item will give it an additional effect from a list of effects unique to Corrupted items. In the case with gems, corrupting one will either yield a corrupted gem (like a fireball with slightly more AOE, and the "Corrupted" effect which prevents crafting with GCP), or a Vaal gem (which is the powerful version of a gem that needs souls to use)

Comment: "Consider it a "pacing mechanic" to balance the fact of `how awesome it is`" Vaal Ground Slam disagrees :p

Comment: Only Vaal gem I use is Skeletons, so no idea how that one plays.